# SSL_do_handshake() get stuck

Tags: c, linux, ssl

in my code i call SSL_do_handshake() function.
Everything works fine if the server gets the "right" messages.
BUT, for security issues I tried sending a dummy message. just "hello" to the right port and the right ip address.
in this case,  SSL_do_handshake() gets stuck forever. 
I want the function to return in that case, so that my server will not get stuck.

What are the options ?

I read about setting bio to non-blocking..
I added to my code :
BIO_set_nbio(bio, 1); before the connection is established..
but it didn't do thew work...

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

BIO_set_nbio sets only the flag, that the bio should be considered non-blocking. You have to actually make the socket itself non-blocking.

Comment: It's there a timeout for ssl handshake ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. But there might be a timeout for reading from  the underlying socket (SO_TIMEOUT). Also a signal could break the read, e.g. use alarm and a SIGALRM handler.

Comment: I tried using this function:
SSL_CTX_set_timeout(ctx, 10); // set for 10 seconds
didn't seem to work.. got any idea why?

Comment: Because you did not read or understand the documentation what this function is for: "SSL_CTX_set_timeout, SSL_CTX_get_timeout - manipulate timeout values for session caching". You are not doing any session caching here, you want to establish a session. Granted, openssl is not easy to understand and has lots of badly or not documented stuff.